# Spring multiple datasource without primary

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, datasource, autowired

I have a problem, I need to create two `DataSource` but I cannot use `@Primary` because in other module I also have two `DataSource` and then in third module I include both modules, so there are two primary modules.

I wanted to use `@Qualifier` but it does not work.

```
@Bean(name = "secondDataSourceProperties")
@ConfigurationProperties("second")
public DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean(name = "secondDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties("second.configuration")
public DataSource secondDataSource(@Qualifier("secondDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
    HikariDataSource ds = dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    ds.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    ds.setConnectionInitSql("SELECT 1");
    ds.setPoolName("jdbc/second");
    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "secondTransactionManager")
public DataSourceTransactionManager secondDataSourceTransactionManager(@Qualifier("secondDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("first")
public DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean(name = "firstDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties("first.configuration")
public DataSource firstDataSource(@Qualifier("firstDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
    HikariDataSource ds = dataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    ds.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    ds.setConnectionInitSql("SELECT 1");
    ds.setPoolName("jdbc/first");
    return ds;
}

@Bean(name = "firstTransactionManager")
public DataSourceTransactionManager firstDataSourceTransactionManager(@Qualifier("firstDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

Error I'm getting is:

> No qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties'
>   available: expected single matching bean but found 5:
>   secondDataSourceProperties,firstDataSourceProperties,3DataSourceProperties,4DataSourceProperties,spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties

I use `DataSource` like that in code:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("first")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

and

```
@Transactional(value = "firstTransactionManager")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just doing the following? Without `@Qualifier` mess? The name of the method for `@Bean` is by default used as the "qualifier" of the bean.

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("first")
public DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("second")
public DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
public DataSource firstDataSource(DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties) {
    HikariDataSource ds = firstDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    ds.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    ds.setConnectionInitSql("SELECT 1");
    ds.setPoolName("jdbc/first");
    return ds;
}

@Bean
public DataSource secondDataSource(DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties) {
    HikariDataSource ds = secondDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    ds.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    ds.setConnectionInitSql("SELECT 1");
    ds.setPoolName("jdbc/second");
    return ds;
}

@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager firstTransactionManager(DataSource firstDataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(firstDataSource);
}

@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager secondTransactionManager(DataSource secondDataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(secondDataSource);
}
```

You can just autowire with this name only;

```
@Autowire
private DataSource firstDateSource;
```

and

```
@Transactional("secondTransactionManager")
```

Comment: Still getting  the error ```Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties' available: expected single matching bean but found 5:```

Comment: It was useful to use just method call  ```HikariDataSource ds = firstDataSourceProperties()......``` instead of passing DataSourceProperties as method argument

Answer (score 0):

Helped adding

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Or if you use @SpringBootApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"a.b.c"}, exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Helped meaning resolved the issue? I thought the naming would've resolved the issue with duplicate beans... I have 10 property beans in same config file, all used independently, and just different naming is enough.

Comment: Please let me know your feedback, just adding an exclusion resolved the issue? If you don't need those beans, why include or have them in your project at all?